# ios/xcode: Get launch image to display

Tags: ios, xcode, launchimage

I have been trying without success to get a launch image (screenshot from app) to display.  I tried adding it as a file named Default.png to the project as apparently people did back in the day.  (Adding icon.png to the project is the only way I've been able to get the icon to appear.)

I also tried the newer version suggested by apple of going into imgcassette and creating a launchImage set.  I don't have separately sized images for all the possible combinations but did drag and drop my screenshot onto most of the spaces (i.e. those for a phone as opposed to iPad).  According to what I've read once you do this, it is supposed to just work.

However, no matter what I do, the image is not displaying.  Instead I just get black screen. My target device is an iPhone 4s running IOS7.

Can anyone suggest what else to try?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you use size xcassets?

Comment: My image cassette by default is Images.xcassets

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to use the asset catalogs or the launchscreen.xib file. 
In the main project file scroll down until you see something similar to this and click "Use Asset Catalog" and then "migrate" or something like that. Also, remove the launchscreen.xib from the "Launch Screen File" if you prefer using the asset catalogs.

[image: set launch image source to using assets]

Next, navigate to Assets.xcassets in the sidebar. There you will see something like the following:

[image: asset catalog]

Here, drag and drop the launchscreen images you imported into your project onto the appropriate slot.

That should do it. 
Hope this helps :)

Comment: Ok.  That did it.  I was reluctant to click migrate but that seemed to fix things.  The only funky thing is there is still an old LaunchImage catalog there where I previously dropped in images.  that apparently isn't getting used.  It named the one created through the migration process LaunchImage-2.

Comment: That definitely is weird. But if the new one works you can delete the old anyway. Happy to help :)

Answer (score 1):

The way I've done it is to click on the project in the Navigator. Then, open the "General" tab. From there scroll down to "Launch Images" and make sure the drop down says "LaunchImage". Then, click the little arrow pointing to the right, which should show you what your current launch images are. If they aren't set to what you are expecting, you will need to set them again.

Comment: There is no arrow to the right (there is for icons but not launch images).  The only option is Use Asset Catalog.  When I click on that it asks if I want to migrate images to a new image set but I'm not sure what else that will do

Comment: I guess I should've asked what version of Xcode you were using. I'm still using Xcode 5.1.1, so I may not be that good of a source. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your project settings are loading your launch image file as the launch image. 
[image: see picture if that doesn't make sense.]

Comment: my screen looks like yours.  But it says Use Asset Catalog rather than pointing to an image.  The Launch Screen File seems to be for using an xib or storyboard.  Should I just change the filename to LaunchScreen?

Comment: Change its value to whatever is storing your launchscreen.

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode go to Supporting Files > LaunchScreen.xib and in the `interface builder` add a `UIImageView` with your image. Then in your project settings set App Icons and Launch Images > Launch Screen File to LaunchScreen.xib

Unfortunately you can't set the LaunchScreen programatically because the splash screen can't be a subclassed `UIViewController`. If you do want to add some sort of animation you could load a `View` that looks exactly like your `LaunchScreen.xib` and animate it from your `AppDelegate`

Comment: There was already a lanuchscreen.xib file that was created when I first created the app and it just has the name of the app.  Come to think of it, this used to load at beginning but no longer does.  In any case, I went ahead and clicked on LaunchScreen.xib in the project settings.  However, the .xib file does not display so no difference--still getting black screen.